# My confusion in docker volume usage in practice

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I see some people define a volume like this (I only put part of the Dockefile below to explain my question clearly):

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . . 
VOLUME . /usr/src/app
```

So, in the VOLUME line, the `.` means the current directory which is the `WORKDIR` defined above. Then, 2nd part for the VOLUME is `/usr/src/app`. Is it a convention? It sounds like the same path defined as volume twice to me. Do I misunderstand it?

Another question is what is the benefit of defining volume `/usr/src/app`? Is the benefit that when making changes in the project it could be reflected in all containers from the same image (because the `COPY . .` copied the project folder to the container)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems like a redundancy - in Dockerfiles, `VOLUME` is just a declaration to copy files from the image to a volume mounted at that location. It [cannot specify the directory in the host](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes), that can only be done at runtime.

`VOLUME` [can take multiple arguments](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume), and declares volumes in all the locations passed - so if you specify the same directory multiple times, it should have no practical effect, despite having two equivalent paths listed.

It could make a difference if you changed the WORKDIR after that line, or in a subsequent image built from that one, since the relative path is resolved only when running the container.

Comment: Note that the copy functionality only works on newly created volumes (either anonymous if you don't declare any or named if you replace your volume definition at run time) and has absolutely no effect if you bind mount a directory from the host.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the dot in `VOLUME . /usr/src/app` is the current location of the host and `/usr/src/app` is a path in container. Do you mean both the dot and the `/usr/src/app` mean the path in container?  And what about my 2nd question, I wonder what are the benefits of doing `VOLUME . /usr/src/app` ( I see some people do so)

Comment: To remove any confusion, you should only have in your Dockerfile: `VOLUME /usr/src/app` and nothing else.

Comment: OK, but I still would like to have an answer to my questions which I mentioned in my previous comment. Even though I understand to use `VOLUME /usr/src/app` is the way to go. My question is about the effect of that dot and the benefits of doing `VOLUME . /usr/src/app` which I see some people use. If just read through my questions in my previous comment. Only after that my (and I believe others') confusion could be resolved.

Comment: Very good points @Zeitounator! Thanks for complementing the information.

Comment: @Leem.fin, is there any big project doing that so we can better judge if there is a legitimate use for it? To mee it seems almost all uses of specifying the `.` would either be useless or lead to confusing behaviour.

Comment: The only effect of having the dot is to add the current `WORKDIR` as a `VOLUME` as well as the second argument. If they are identical it only adds one volume. If not you have two volumes. If you add a workdir change later in your Dockerfile, that changes the defined volumes. My 2 cent: just don't do this unless you want to have endless conversation about the confusion it produces in SO comments :) To go further, copying your application sources in a dir to later make that directory a Volume is very strange IMO. You usually want this data to be immutable inside your container.

Comment: @LeonardoDagnino do you also feel the copying application sources in a dir to later make that directory a Volume is very strange like @Zeitounator said in above comment? It refers to `VOLUME /usr/src/app`, or do you know any benefits of doing that?

Comment: Yes, I agree, and actually hadn't paid attention to the volume being the same directory you just copied to. It is very strange, since actually mounting a volume there with `-v directory:/usr/src/app` would lead to your files in the container disappearing, as @Zeitounator first pointed out. Any potential benefits would eventually lead to confusion eventually. So I'd rather just not do it, too.